# Javascript return with called method

Tags: javascript, frontend

What I want is if function2 returns then I don't perform "otherstuff" in function1 (I want a way to bail out of the function externally), if it doesn't return then I go to "otherstuff"

can someone help?

explanation of functions:

```
function function1(){
    function2();
    other stuff
}

function function2(){
    if(somecond) {
        return;
    }
    if(somecond) {
        return;
    }
    if(somecond) {
        dontreturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Return `true` or `false`, then just do `if (function2()) //return true else //returned false`

Comment: let function2 return a boolean value. `if (function2()) otherStuff();`

Comment: If the function doesn't return, then you never get back to `function1`, you're in `function2` forever.

Answer (score 1):

Have your `function2` return a boolean, and based off that, decide whether or not to run more code:

```
if (function2()) {
    //returned true
} else {
    //returned false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function function1(){
  if(!function2())
  {
  //do other stuff.
  }
}

function function2(){
  if(somecond){
   return;
  }
  if(somecond)
  {
   return;
  }
  if(somecond){
   return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
function function1(){
    if (function2()){
        other stuff
    }
}

function function2(){
    if(somecond){
        return false;
    } else if(somecond){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** about

> *return* or *not*

It's about

> *don't return* or *return something*

You can return whatever you want. Even if you don't return anything the function will return `undefined` anyway.

In your particular case I suggest returning a boolean (true|false):

```
function function1() {
    if (!function2()) {
        //other stuff
    }
}

function function2() {
    if (somecond) {
        return true;
    }
    if (somecond) {
        return true;
    }
    if (somecond) {
        return false;
    }
}
```